# PHP Copy failed to open stream - invalid arguments

Tags: php

When I try to copy the image at this url, it fails with:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: 
"Warning: copy(lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2016/6HT_0140_002R.jpg]&amp;set=key[rotate],value[0.3]&amp;set=key[width],value[1929]&amp;set=key[height],value[2256]&amp;set=key[x],value[1720]&amp;set=key[y],value[202]&amp;set=key[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&amp;hmver=0&amp;set=key[quality],value[80]&amp;set=key[size],value[346x405]&amp;call=url[file:/mobile/v2/product]): 
failed to open stream: Invalid argument"
```

Code

```
copy('lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2016/6HT_0140_002R.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[0.3]&set=key[width],value[1929]&set=key[height],value[2256]&set=key[x],value[1720]&set=key[y],value[202]&set=key[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&hmver=0&set=key[quality],value[80]&set=key[size],value[346x405]&call=url[file:/mobile/v2/product]', 'file.jpeg');
```

Any idea why and what I could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `http://` in your URL. `copy` assumes you are trying to access a file on your local filesystem if you do not specify a protocol. PHP uses the protocol to determine which wrapper to use when finding the file.

Read this page for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this (working code):

```
copy('http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2016/6HT_0140_002R.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[0.3]&set=key[width],value[1929]&set=key[height],value[2256]&set=key[x],value[1720]&set=key[y],value[202]&set=key[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&hmver=0&set=key[quality],value[80]&set=key[size],value[346x405]&call=url[file:/mobile/v2/product]', __DIR__.'/file.jpeg');
```

Your code doesn't work because you are missing `http` part of you image url.